# detect nodes last position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, position

I create an game that include balls that has gravity and restitution properties (every ball has different properties by random function). now I want to detect the last position of each ball and then call a remove from node function. Im using the update function to detected the position of the ball while its jumping on the screen. im not sure if I can and how can I  detect its last position. Im thinking about create an array that will store each position but I not sure if its right way and wonder if there is a simpler and better way. 
here is my code for now:

```
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "BALL") { (node:SKNode, nil) in
        print(node.position)
    }
}
```

can you help me with that? the array option is only way or there is another one and better one?

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the ball and add your own property that stores the position.

```
class BallNode: SKShapeNode {
    var lastPosition: CGPoint?
}

let ball = BallNode()
ball.name = “BALL”
ball.position = CGPoint.zero
self.addChild(ball)
```

In update....

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "BALL") { (node:BallNode, nil) in
        print(node.position)
        if let last= node.lastPosition {
            print(last)
            // do something with last
        }
        //Update last position before end of updatE
        node.lastPosition = node.position

    }
}
```

Comment: should I subclass the ball? right now I have a function createBall () -> SKNode, is it ok or I have to/ its better to do it via subclass?

Comment: If you don't subclass it, you wont be able to do it the way i've suggested here.

Comment: but I get confused while im trying to do so. I set a class as you mention but when I try so set it as skshapenode I get an error that say "cannot assign a value of type 'skshapenode' to type 'GameScence.BallNode". I need the ball to type skshapenode because it has a physic properties

Comment: Then just subclass it from `SKShapeNode`, like this: `class BallNode: SKShapeNode {`

Comment: o.k. sorry for the ignorantly (im quit new)... where should I set its init? at 'touch began' (because it position depends on the position of the touch)  or inside my GameScene class?

Comment: I don't understand that last question.  If you have something relating to how to init a class or overriding that, you should post a different question.

Comment: my problem is when I set the class as SKShapeNode and try to set init the ball size with "init(circleOfRadius:)" I always get an error.

Comment: hi, I just tried your answer and it just not working. when I create a class for the ball i just can't get the properties inside it (just looking for the nodes name = BALL and set it as 'node'). because f that I can't access the lastPosition property.t there is a way to solve it?

Comment: I️ don’t understand your problem.  Post a new question and feel free to come back here with the link.